# jQuery-based round corner buttons (non flat)

Tags: jquery, rounded-corners

I am trying to make buttons that will have rounded corner and will have some gradient color scheme on it. I know these sorts of buttons are easy to make with images, but due to the nature of the application I'm working on, we have decided not to use image, instead just CSS and JavaScript/JQuery.

Does anyone know any trick or have seen anything like this? I have tried the JQuery Rounded Corner (http://www.appnovation.com/rounded-corners-jquery, http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/). These are all good to make rounded corners but inside, they all hold only flat colors, no gradient or shadow outside. Does anyone know any trick or any site that has some example?

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/

Comment: Have either of the answers below helped you? If so, may I suggest that you vote them up and/or mark them as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are TONS of tutorials that can be found with a quick Google search. I suggest starting here:

http://www.schillmania.com/content/entries/2009/css3-and-the-future/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried rolling your own theme?  you can do all sorts of cool things :)

[Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)